# No sound via HDMI and I cannot use mirror display on a lenovo G560

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

Had some trouble since switching from Win to Ubuntu yesterday. When I connect my pc through HDMI to my TV the sound doesn't work. The video is there (expanded desktop) but the sound is still coming from the PC.

I want to be able to mirror the display and guess this could solve the problem. But when I try the TV gets no display, just black, and no signal. Anyone know in what direction to push me? Don't want to back to Win, but with no way to watch movies on the TV it's heading that way...

It's an integrated intel vid card.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. For some reason Alsa couldn't manage it but when installing Pulse I had the choice to switch to HDMI audio, which ment the audio worked on the TV. Still NOGO on the mirroring, but no need. found out I rather use the PS3 Media server anyway to watch movies...